# Encoding and Webpages and utf8?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, encoding, utf-8

*I already know that utf is for "How I store it" , and it has benefit cause it has a variable length which can be useful for web.*

**Q#1**

1) when I declare

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"    content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

is it for

- **How** the html  file itself is stored in my hard drive ?
- Or -  **how** should the document should be transmitted to the client ( every char in document will be downloaded as a utf 8 char?)
- Or -  when a user will fill a form and submit - **How** should the browser transmit to the server each char in the form input+html

**Q#2**

2) if utf-8 can contain it all , why I sometime see `charset=windows-1255"` ? why they don't always use `utf8` and having fun ?

Comment: You should read [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/06/all-about-unicode-utf8-character-sets/) and [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-web-character-encoding/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of the `Content-Type` charset is an indicator to the client what charset the received text is encoded in. The client should take appropriate action with regards to the document regardless of what encoding is used, whether that is storing the raw bytes and the charset declaration, or decoding the text into a neutral charset, or whatnot.

Comment: what about submitting ? I didnt understand the  last part of your answer.

Comment: The client is responsible for telling the server what charset is being used during submission. The last part can be simplified as follows: "2. Who cares. The client is responsible for dealing with it regardless of what encoding is used."

Comment: isnt the client suppose to send the same charset that it came with ? I mean can a client get a ut8 charset page and send something else ?

Comment: Anyone can send anything with any charset, **as long as they tell the other side what they're using**.

Comment: An HTML webform submits data using the same charset as the containing page unless the `<form>` tag explicitally states a different charset.

Comment: @Remy: Is that mandated somewhere, or is it a convention employed by browsers?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: it is dictated by the official HTML specs. The `accept-charset` attribute of the `form` element, defined in [HTML4 Section 17.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) and [HTML5 Section 4.10.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element), sets the charset used for submitting a form, and defaults to the page's charset if omitted. Rules for submitting forms are defined in [HTML4 Section 17.13](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13) and [HTML5 Section 4.10.22](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0).

Comment: "The default value for this attribute is the reserved string "UNKNOWN". User agents may interpret this value as the character encoding that was used to transmit the document containing this FORM element." So, if it's not there then anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Q1. The meta content-type tells the browser how to interpret the bytes received from the server. It's up to you to save the file in the encoding specified by the `meta` tag. A server may set a Character Set in the `Content-Type` header but this may not match the actual file as there's no 100% reliable way to detect a file's encoding. The bytes of the file are transferred the same regardless of Character Set.

According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_accept_charset.asp, the page's content type can also influence the character set that the browser uses to encode data when posting forms from the page.

Q2. Good question. I believe Character Sets are still much miss-understood, so it's not unusual for encoding not to match with the header defined by the developer. Legacy apps may not be able to write UTF-8. Also there's a small byte saving when using a specific 8bit char set when an equivalent character in UTF-8 takes more bytes. For example, the Euro symbol can be represented in Windows-1252 using 8 bits but 24 bits in UTF-8

Comment: so when I write in my html `content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`  - I must save the _file_ in my HD _also_ as utf8 ? what about if i send the file to you ? how would you(or your computer) know  how to interpret the bytes (as utf8 i mean)?

Comment: @royinamir indeed, the tag is metadata to describe the file encoding (the mapping of bytes to characters). As I've said, there's no reliable detection method so the tag is there to allow the browser to display the bytes correctly. The browser would look for this tag and adjust the character set accordingly.

Comment: Small Question : if there are bytes on a hard drive which represents a file. does windows can recognize what is the encoding ? (according to the bytes stored on HD)

Comment: It's impossible to be 100% sure what encoding the bytes of a file are in. A BOM at the start of the file wil be a good indication but otherwise you will just have to make an educated guess. There are  a number of open source tools and libraries, which can give a scored guess of the encoding based on hints. For example, multi-byte UTF-8 sequences are pretty unique.

Comment: So if the computer can know what os the encoding , why should i specify it also in the html ?????

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. The computer *can't* know the encoding for sure unless it's specified either in the file or by metadata. The guessing algorithms are far from perfect, especially when working with 7/8bit char sets.